# When A mirrors B

Tags: grammar

When A mirrors B. Should what is mirrored be repeated in the second instance?

> The large number of skirts was mirrored in the large number of
>   participants.
>   The large number of skirts was mirrored in the number
>   of participants.
>   The large number of skirts was mirrored in the
>   participants.

Comment: Your question is reasonable but your example of skirts is not. You would never say that skirts were *mirrored*. Moreover, if you mean here that the skirts are being worn by the participants then this is an incorrect use of *mirror*, which is metaphorical and not literal. For a property or thing to *mirror* you need two objects: B that has has property and A that also has the property (i.e. *mirrors* it) but is distinct from B.

Answer (score -1):

No, what is mirrored is not repeated in the second instance, at least not in the sense given in your examples. Try googling "was mirrored in" for examples of usage. One I've just found is "His own shock was mirrored in her face." So, we can look at *his* shocked face and see the same expression (mirrored) in *her* face. Or, "The economic recovery in Britain was mirrored in the US." So, we look at the economic recovery in Britain and see the same recovery (mirrored) in the US. Or, "Jim's tiresome pedantry was mirrored in his turgid prose." So, we look at Jim being tiresomely pedantic and see the same quality in his writing. That sort of thing.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question posed.